# TexMaker Calling Old File

Tags: bibtex, formatting

I've created a reference list and called it `References.bib` and put one citation in as a trial and everything was fine. However, I altered the text in the file `References.bib` to show a new citation, and deleted the old citation. Now when I call `References.bib`, it still shows the old citation despite their being no text to do with that citation, and does not show the new one. It seems like its pulling the old citation out of thin air. My code is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\geometry{left=0.9in,right=0.9in,top=1in,bottom=1in}

\begin{document}
\title{Why are Hydrogen Cars Rarely Seen?}
\author{Thomas Breust - u7106139} 
\date{}
\maketitle
\addtolength{\baselineskip}{.15\baselineskip}   

blah blah blah 

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{References.bib}
\end{document}
```

The code for the `References.bib` file is

```
@article{dowling_2019,
    title={Hyundai Nexo: first hydrogen car certified for Australia, now for the refuelling stations},
    url={https://www.caradvice.com.au/805257/hyundai-nexo-certified-australia/},                    journal={caradvice},
    author={Dowling, Joshua}, 
    year={2019}, 
    month={Nov}
    
}
```

The output of the references list looks like

Thomas, C. E. (2010, Jul). Hydrogen-powered fuel cell electric vehicles compared to the alternatives. AZO Cleantech. Retrieved from https://www.azocleantech.com/ article.aspx?ArticleID=214

Clearly that is not the citation that is written in my file `References.bib`. Would anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: Did you recompile with bibtex?  if you remove the auxiliary `.bbl` file the old reference will disappear.

Comment: As Guido pointed out, to refresh your biblio, you need to run PdfLatex + BibTex + PdfLatex (x2). When you run BibTex, does the Message/Log window show any errors? Another possibility is that TexMaker working folder is different from your main file. Do you have more than one copy of your project?